# Why an action is not defined in action-creator function in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

While trying to make a simple appointment app using react-redux, I get an error where one item (lastname) in the action is not defined. The other two items (firstname and id) are properly defined. Why would this action item be not defined while others are defined? I feel i am missing a key concept in react-redux. Can you explain why the action is not defined and how to correct it?
action-creator:

```
import { ADD_BOOKING, DELETE_BOOKING } from "../constants";

const uid = () => Math.random().toString(34)

export const addBooking=function (firstname,lastname){

    const action={
        type:ADD_BOOKING,
        payload:{firstname,     
                lastname,
                id:uid()

        }
    }
console.log('action in addBooking',action);
return action;
}

export const deleteBooking = (id) => {
    const action = {
        type: DELETE_BOOKING,
        id: id
    };
    console.log("deleting in actions", action);
    return action;
};
```

reducer:

```
import { ADD_BOOKING, DELETE_BOOKING} from "../constants";


const booking = action => {
    return {
        firstname: action.payload.firstname,
        lastname: action.payload.lastname,
        id: action.payload.id
    };
};

const removeById = (state = [], id) => {
    //filter those not clicked
    const bookings = state.filter(booking => booking.id !==id);
    console.log("new reduced bookings", bookings);
    return bookings;
};

const bookings = (state = [], action) => {
    let bookings = null;
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_BOOKING:
            bookings = [...state, booking(action)];
            console.log("bookings as state", bookings);
            return bookings;
        case DELETE_BOOKING:
            bookings = removeById(state, action.id);
            return bookings;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export {bookings};
```

Console log:
[image: console log:]

Component (App.jsx):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { addBooking, deleteBooking } from "../actions";
import { Header } from "./NavigationBar";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class App extends Component {
  //Initialize the Component
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      duedate: ""
    };
  }
  //add Booking
  addBooking() {
    this.props.addBooking(this.state.firstname);
    this.props.addBooking(this.state.lastname);

  }

  //delete Booking
  deleteBooking(id) {
    this.props.deleteBooking(id);
  }
  //render the bookings
  renderBookings() {
    //access our bookings

   const {bookings} = this.props;

    return (
      <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
        { bookings.map(booking => {
            return (<li key={ booking.id } className="list-group item">
                      <div className="list-item">
                        { booking.firstname }
                      </div>
                      <div className="list-item">
                        { booking.lastname }
                      </div>

                      <div className="btn btn-danger" onClick={ () => this.deleteBooking(booking.id) }>
                        Cancel Booking

                      </div>
                    </li>)
          }) }
      </ul>)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="form-inline booking-form">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter First Name"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  firstname: event.target.value
                })
              }
            />
            <input
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter Last Name"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  lastname: event.target.value
                })
              }
            />
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="datetime-local"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  duedate: event.target.value
                })
              }
            />

            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-success"
              onClick={() => this.addBooking()}
            >
              Add Booking
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.renderBookings()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    bookings: state
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  addBooking,
  deleteBooking
})(App);
```

Comment: From this code I don't see why that would be happening. It's most likely a problem where your action is being dispatched. Can you post the code from the component where the action is being dispatched?

Comment: @Austin Greco I have added App.jsx, to be frank my understanding dispatched action is limited.

Comment: It looks like it's just how you're calling it - the `addBooking` function in App.jsx calls the `addBooking` action with the first name as its only input and then with the last name as its only input. The first input is always going to be first name, since that's how you've defined the action. It might be a little easier to name general functions differently from actions to help keep things straight.

Comment: @mef79 I understood your comment as renaming the `addBooking` function in App.jsx would probably resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your `addBooking` function with only one parameter, but you call it twice. It returns two actions with each values assigned to `firstname`. Instead, do this: `this.props.addBooking(this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname);`. That will solve your issue.

Comment: Actions should dispatched inside of dispatch(). See the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) for Redux.

Comment: Unless you use connect which binds the dispatch for you, like in this case.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know connect took action creators as a second argument! TIL

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wrapping `App` with `connect`, `App` now has the ability to `dispatch` actions. `dispatch` can be accessed via props with `this.props.dispatch`. So instead of `this.props.addBooking` use `this.props.dispatch(addBooking())`.

Also you can edit

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  addBooking,
  deleteBooking
})(App);
```

to

```
export default connect()(App)
```

More on connect [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples). Connect is used to cherry pick specific parts of the store and expose them to whatever component you are wrapping. In this case you just want to use your actions, and are importing them at the top of App.jsx

Even though you're calling addBooking()/deleteBooking() it is not flowing through the correct channels (`dispatch`) for Redux to know to update the store, so the values come back as undefined.

Comment: The other values "firstname" and "id" were rendered. @gretro answer solved the issue, but I wonder what impact omitting dispatch would have?